# How to mock a DLL Import

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, dllimport, extern

I'm trying to write unit test case of a class which uses Dll imports like below

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string name, string windowName);
```

In order to test the class I want to mock the above statement using MOQ but not able to figure out how to setup a mock for it.

Also would like to know whether the above is achievable or not..if not then what needs to be done in order to make it testable.

I know that to make this class testable we need to create wrappers over these statements and would need to separate it out in a separate class.

Would like to know is there any other option to achieve the same.

Comment: But with DLL import static is must

Comment: Sure, but you can simply hide the call to that static method into a call to another method.

Comment: Yes..but then when I'll try writing unit test for that wrapper class I'll be in the same situation

Comment: I know that we need to draw a line as upto which level unit test cases can be written..

Comment: DllImport is a *declaration*, not a method. The equivalent is an assembly reference. It's good practice to put all DllImport declarations in a single class anyway.

Answer (score 3):

actually you can mock methods from exported Dlls by using typemock Isolator, and without any unnecessary changes in your code.
you just need to export the Dll and mock the method as any other static method,
for example:

```
public class ClassUnderTest
    {

        public bool foo()
        {
            if(Dependecy.FindWindow("bla","bla") == null)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

public class Dependecy
{//imported method from dll
     [DllImport("user32.dll")]
     public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string name, string windowName);
 }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            //setting a mocked behavior for when the method will be called
            Isolate.WhenCalled(() => Dependecy.FindWindow("", "")).WillReturn(new IntPtr(5));

            ClassUnderTest classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest();
            var res = classUnderTest.foo();

            Assert.IsTrue(res);
        }
```

You can see more about Pinvoked Methods [here](https://www.typemock.com/docs?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Fcontrollingpinvokemethods.htm)

Comment: I want to do the same using MOQ..we are using MOQ framework to mock our dependencies...cannot use any other framework...but thanks for showing that if we use Type mocks we can actually mock DLL import calls too.Up voted your answer but cannot mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can´t mock a static method but only interfaces or classes with virtual members. However you can wrap the method into a virtual one that you can wrap:

```
interface StaticWrapper
{
    InPtr WrapStaticMethod(string name, string windowName);
}
class MyUsualBehaviour : IStaticWrapper
{
    public InPtr WrapStatic(string name, string windowName)
    {
        // here we do the static call from extern DLL
        return FindWindow(name, widnowName);
    }
}
```

However you can now mock that interface instead of the static method:

```
var mock = new Moq<IStaticWrapper>();
mock.Setup(x => x.WrapStatic("name", "windowName")).Returns(whatever);
```

Furthermore you aren´t calling the extern method in your code but only the wrapper which reduces code-coupling to that specific library.

See this link for further explanation an idea: http://adventuresdotnet.blogspot.de/2011/03/mocking-static-methods-for-unit-testing.html

Comment: @RishiTiwari why don't you do it then? What you ask is the equivalent of "How can I mock an assembly reference"? A DllImport isn't a method to mock, it's a *declaration* - a reference to a specific entry point in a library. It's actually good practice to collect DllImport declarations in a single class.

Comment: I just want to know whether it is possible or not to mock a DLL import...to make it testable I know that a wrapper is required,Thanks anyways

Comment: @RishiTiwari As I already mentioned this is not possible for the mentioned reasons. A reference to an assembly is something static within your project. You can´t simply say: reference that assembly only then and then, but for testing I´d like to forget about that.

Comment: Replace `dll import` with `assembly reference` in your statement. Does it make sense? How would you mock an assembly reference? You wouldn't, you'd use a common interface and a mock that implements it. Hence, the wrapper